# Replace a specific character in a dataframe column with another character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
       symbol                      date      open     high      low    close        volume
0    BTC/USDT 2020-03-28 00:00:00+00:00   6243.25   6298.5   6028.0   6237.5  3.888942e+03
1    BTC/USDT 2020-03-29 00:00:00+00:00   6233.50   6262.5   5869.5   5876.5  1.140766e+05
2    BTC/USDT 2020-03-30 00:00:00+00:00   5876.00   6609.0   5856.0   6396.5  2.242312e+05
3    BTC/USDT 2020-03-31 00:00:00+00:00   6397.00   6523.5   6330.5   6411.0  1.702458e+05
4    BTC/USDT 2020-04-01 00:00:00+00:00   6410.00   6685.5   6155.5   6646.0  6.872307e+05
..        ...                       ...       ...      ...      ...      ...           ...
599  BTC/USDT 2021-11-17 00:00:00+00:00  60060.00  60820.0  58347.0  60348.0  1.627009e+08
600  BTC/USDT 2021-11-18 00:00:00+00:00  60348.00  60955.0  56474.0  56891.0  1.905533e+08
```

I need to replace the "/" in the symbol column with "-".

Code I have tried:

```
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].replace(['/'], '-')
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].replace(['/'], '-', inplace=True)
df['symbol'] = df.replace('/', '-')
df = df.replace(to_replace='\/', value='-', regex=True)
```

I know it's something simple, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Have you tried `df['symbol'].str.replace('/', '-')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `str`:

```
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].str.replace('/', '-')
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to give "thanks" comments...but "thanks".  It may not show from my original post - I tried to keep it brief - but I worked on this for hours, and your solution did not show up in any searches.  Thanks again!